# Cannot see default Nginx landing page in browser

Tags: nginx, digital-ocean

I am trying to do a simple nginx setup on my DO droplet.

Following this tutorial : https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-nginx-on-ubuntu-16-04

After the installation when i check for running status using `systemctl status nginx` I get no issues:
[Screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/cEAspn1.png)

However, when i try to access the server using browser `http://ip_address` i get no default nginx landing page(as mentioned in the post). I only see `cannot GET \` and 404 not found in network window.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Did you open the port in the firewall?

Comment: @NasirRiley you mean using `sudo ufw allow 'Nginx HTTP'`? Yeah i did. `sudo ufw status` shows Nginx - Allow - Anywhere